# My Portable Hard Drive with USB3 didn't work when connected to My Laptop, but it working with USB2 properly

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage, usb-3

I have [Western Digital](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?modelno=WDBACY5000ABK-EESN&x=0&y=0) My Passport Essential Portable Hard Drive with USB3 and `Model:WDBACY5000ABK-EESN`.

Until about two or three months ago when I connected that to My Laptop USB3 port, that worked very well. But now when I'm connecting that to My device, The system
does not detect any Hard Drives. When plug in the USB2 port is working properly. I connected that to another Laptop with USB3 port but I had the same problem. I tested My Laptop port with a Flash Memory by USB3 and ports were healthy and I'm sure they are working. For this issue, I changed the windows, but it still did not work. What can I do?

Comment: Hi can you provide the specific laptop you have?

Comment: Yes, I have ASUS A53SV with CPU: Intel Core I7 2670QM, 8Gb of RAM 1333 MHZ, 750Gb H.D.D, VGA Geforce GT 540M 2GB and 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate. Also I checked that to Lenovo Idea Pad Z580 and My External Hard didn't work.

Comment: that is a very odd problem indeed. The fact that the hard drive didn't work on another computer strikes out the possibility that it is your usb3 drivers. If you can, obtain another cable that is used with usb3 device and see if that works. Sometime the cable could be defective.

Comment: @AlanTurin, you are right. My Passport has got warranty. I went to support center and they said to me the Hard Drive cables often has problem. I changed my Hard cable and it works well. Thank you for your comments and please write your comment into the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very odd problem indeed. The fact that the hard drive didn't work on another computer strikes out the possibility that it is your usb3 drivers. If you can, obtain another cable that is used with usb3 device and see if that works. Sometime the cable could be defective.

As confirmed by the WD support center, you resolved the problem by replacing the cable on your USB 3 device, since it was indeed faulty.